# kinect xbox visual studio, System.AccesViolationException

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm just starting to try develop an kinect application.
The problem is when I'm trying to run the project sample from Kinect SDK 1.0
it shows a message dialog. Here is the message.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Microsoft.Kinect.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

It occurs in
`sensor.Start();`
from the code.

How do I overcome this problem?

note:
I'm using kinect for xbox.

--EDIT--
Updating the SDK solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the latest SDK installed, that is likely the problem.  The latest version is 1.6 and many things have changed.

If you don't have the latest version installed, you should.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/

**Don't learn how to develop for the Kinect using an outdated SDK!**  It has changed a lot and you are doing yourself a great disservice by trying to do so.

There are multiple examples released by Microsoft with the SDK that show you halos to get started, and much more.  Use those to help you learn, not someting written for an SDK that is no longer supported.

Comment: So if you do have the latest, that is the problem, and if you don't, you should get it?

Comment: If you try to run code based on a beta SDK with a release SDK, that is very different, then it will likely not work.  It absolutely will not work in the case of the Kinect SDK.  So, that would be the problem here.  You also shouldn't learn on an outdated SDK that isn't compatible with the new releases.